# How to retrieve id value based on other column value(SQLiteOpenHelper)?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

[image: The table I want to analyze]

I want to make a login option by verifying if the username and the password contain the same id. The problem is I don't know how to get the id value based on their column value (for example - player or 1234). The result i want to get is to compare between their id values so i can know if the username and the password are correct.

Comment: What dataBase aye you using ? @MaayanKaidar

Comment: SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: You should learn SQL basics: `SELECT ID WHERE UserName = 'player' AND Password = '1234'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method in your SQLiteOpenhelper subclass to return true or false if the username and the password match e.g.

```
public boolean ifValidUserLogin(String username, String password) {
    SQLitedarabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
    Cursor csr = db.query(YOUR_TABLE_NAME,
        null,    // null equates to all columns
        "username" + "=? AND " +
            "password" + "=?", // the WHERE clause less WHERE
        new String[]{username,password}, // the arguments that replace ?'s
        null,null,null
    };
    boolean rv = (csr.getCount > 0);
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

You then invoke this, probably in an activity, which would be along the lines of :-

```
MySQLiteOpenHelper myhlpr = new MySQLiteOpenhelper(this); // parms might be different
if (myhlpr.ifValidUserLogin(username_from_ui,password_from_ui)) {
    // username and password match so do what you need to do here!
} else {
    // mismatch so do what you need to do here!.
}
```

### Notes

- the call to the SQLiteDatabase query method equates to using the SQL `SELECT * FROM table WHERE username=?????? AND password=???????` (??? denoting user input values)
- YOUR_TABLE_NAME should be replaced by the name of the table as a String.
- You may wish to have a look at [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

---

If you wanted the id rather then you could use :-

```
public long getValidUserId(String username, String password) {
    long rv = -1; // default to mismatch and thus no id (could use 0)
    SQLitedarabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
    Cursor csr = db.query(YOUR_TABLE_NAME,
        null,    // null equates to all columns
        "username" + "=? AND " +
            "password" + "=?", // the WHERE clause less WHERE
        new String[]{username,password}, // the arguments that replace ?'s
        null,null,null
    };
    if (csr.moveToFirst) {
        rv = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("YOUR_ID_COLUMNNAME"));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- Obviously you'd call getValidUserId and check for a value > -1 for a match.

Answer (score 0):

you can use query like :

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMP
                + " WHERE  " + KEY_USERNAME + " = '" + userName + "'"
```

assuming your username must be unique to get the unique record.If you want more specific then you can add a condition for password too.

Comment: I'm not programming with SQL but with SQLite, i think it's kinda mixed with java, so I can't just type what you said, correct me if I'm wrong. I'm new for that.

Comment: @MaayanKaidar SQLite uses SQL as its quey language. That's what SQL means in **SQL**ite's name.

Comment: you can take a look at this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_select_query.htm to learn sqllite

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply check if your password match your username and forget about the id?